# Database design of managing clients for multiple businesses

Tags: mysql, laravel, database-design

I have been racking my brain on this for a while. Here's my situation.

I am building a website that will provide scheduling services for businesses. These businesses provide a service to their clients. I would like for each of these businesses to manage their own clients, so they should be able to create clients at will. The businesses may have the same clients. I'm fine with having a clients table with a client_id and business_id column that relate the client to that business. This way each business can manage their own client, I'm fine with duplicates like that. Columns I'm thinking of are email, first_name, last_name, address blah blah all the basic contact info. However, email can't be required as in this industry there could be potential for clients to not have an email address. The businesses should be able to book a client for services.

I would also like the clients to be able to book services with a business through my website. If they book through the website that is the best source of truth for me so I would like to capture that data use this to build a table of customers for me. If they do book through my site they should be able to see a history of services booked. On the flip side, if a business books their client through the back end application, and 3 months down the road the client decides to book through my website on the front end, I would like to recognize that and allow both the client and the business to see past and present bookings.

**What I have tried**

[image]

This allows businesses to create clients at will and manage their own clients. If they provide an email address for the client I create a customer in the customer table for me. Then when a customer decides to register for the website I create the user in the users table and link it to the customer, which can be linked to multiple client records in the clients table since a business could potentially have the same client. But this way at least I have a unique customer record, and the customer can manage their own contact information which will be stored in the customer table, and the business can manage their own version of their client.

This seems to work pretty well, a problem arises when I go to bill the client. I am going to use stripe to process credit card payments on behalf of the business. Where do I store this stripe data that is related to the customer/client? Common sense says to store it in the customers table, however what if the business doesn't create an email for the client when booking a service?

I hope this make some sense to someone. Has anyone ever ran into an issue of managing clients for multiple businesses? Where those clients are also your customers of your website. It's like a single record (client/customer) belongs to three different entities (business, website and the client themselves). Me being the website, I don't need to manage the client/customers data, whatever they give me I'll take. But the business may want to manage it themselves.

Just looking for some ideas of what others may do in this situation.

Comment: Please add some code instead of long explanation. That will give you more answers.

Comment: I don't have enough points to add images, there is a link there that shows my initial idea. This really isn't a code question so I don't have any code to show, it's more of a database design question which requires some explanation. I know it's long an ugly but there is no better way to get the details out there.

Comment: Hello @KyleReierson How did you do with this approach? I was thinking in something similar because I'm facing almost the same situation. I was more into having a customerId and a clientId on the user table or something like that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A client should be able to give info on a business-by-business basis. That includes to you as a business. Your business (with them) just happens to be giving them access to other businesses.

(Note that you cannot know whether a client of another business is the same person as a client of yours unless they sign up with you while logged in to one of your businesses or sign up with a business while logged in as a registered user with you. Ditto for any two businesses you support.)

Comment: Thanks @philipxy. That is kind of the conclusion I am coming to. Initially I was thinking, if a business created a client for themselves, and added an email address, I would capture that email in the customer table as well for myself. Then if the customer created an account with me down the road I could recognize that and link the user table to the customer table, which is related to multiple clients. I think I will just go the route of keeping them separate. If they book through my site they are my customer, and if they book a service by calling the business they are their client.

Comment: I couldn't agree more with what @phiipxy wrote. Especially with the 2nd part of it.

Comment: @KyleReierson I am concerned that you think your comment adds to your question. My 1st paragraph says, you probably don't want the many:many. My 2nd says that if you do want it then it's not enough for a person to have created an account, they have to have created an account while logged into another account.. Ie "if the customer created an account with me down the road I could recognize that and link the user table to the customer table" begs the question of how you recognized that it was the same customer. (I just edited my answer to be clearer.)